# How can I make a jquery styleBox trigger when focused using tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some styleBox elements that aren't triggering when I tab through the items.  Does the change() also get triggered on focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation for `.change()`:

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.

See [here for details.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

May be better to use [`.focus()` if you can.](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)